# What are difference betweeen the Quotation marks " " and「」? And How do we use them?

Tags: difference

I have recently come across the quotation marks " " and「」in the texts of video games. I am wondering what situations suit for the use of each quotation mark, because I felt like I saw them being used interchangeably.
I have come across another post that has mentioned other forms of quotations used in Chinese such as 《》 书名号, which is used for books. However, I am a bit unclear about the difference between" " and「」, or if they are actually interchangeable.

Lastly, on my computer, I can only find the quotation marks【】. I am not sure if using that is acceptable as 「」 or not.

If possible, please give me some examples! An example that includes both quotations being used would be appreciated. (Unless that is not possible and I am mistaken haha.)

Thank you.

Comment: Please check out the wikipedia page: [維基標點符號](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hant/%E6%A0%87%E7%82%B9%E7%AC%A6%E5%8F%B7).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under normal circumstances, “” is used in modern Chinese (Mandarin/Putonghua/simplified Chinese), mostly used in written language in mainland China.

while「」is used in ancient Chinese (Cantonese/Traditional Chinese).  mostly used in written language in Hong Kong, Macao, and Taiwan, because these areas still writing in the traditional way.

Also, in vertical text, simplified Chinese uses 「」 as well. (mainly because vertical texts are normally used in traditional things)

But in daily life, there are cases of misuse and mixed-use. Sometimes people deliberately use 「」to express ancient feelings.

Example:

--大家认为他的画作“形神兼备，充满风骨”。
--大家認為他的畫作「形神兼備，充滿風骨」。

(Btw this is my first time to answer, so interesting there!)

Comment: Very good explanation. Just one reminder, even though Cantonese is one of the very important Chinese speaking languages, it is still a regional dialect, and can't be considered equal to the traditional Chinese language, which contains many regional dialects.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "can't be considered equal"? Linguistically, Mandarin isn't superior to any of the Chinese language families. In fact, linguistically, no language is superior to any other language.

Comment: Welcome! And very good first answer you have here! Also, um, do you (or the comment section) by any chance, know how to find the「」key on the computer? I can't seem to find it on my current SoGou keyboard.

Comment: @Monokuma With SoGou input selected, you can input「 and 」pressing ctrl+shift+z and then selecting 标点符号. Without SoGou, in programs supporting Unicode input (like Microsoft Word), Alt+12300, Alt+12301, Alt+65089, and Alt+65090 for 「, 」, ﹁, and ﹂ respectively. Alt+number means you have to keep Alt pressed while typing the number. The number must be typed on the numeric keypad.